# How to add extra-host in windows container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a problem when adding an entry to the hosts file in a windows container. The `extra-hosts` and `add-host` options do not work with windows containers for that reason I have to add it from the dockerfile. I've also tried adding them with double quotes, but with the same result.

```
## Start with a base image with all the necessary tooling to compile our app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2 AS build

## Declare arguments
ARG CONFIG=Debug

## Set the working directory inside compilation container to c:\app
WORKDIR /app

## Skip extraction of XML docs - generally not useful within an image/container - helps performance
ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip
 
## Copy everything from solution dir into the c:\app
COPY . .

## Restore nuget packages
RUN nuget restore

## Use msbuild to publish project, which includes only binaries and content files (no sources)
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=$env:CONFIG /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishUrl="C:\Publish" /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish -r:False

## Start with new base image for running asp.net apps (which contains IIS)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2 AS runtime

RUN echo 10.0.0.001 my.url-1.com >> "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
RUN echo 10.0.0.002 my.url-2.com >> "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

## Set default work folder to c:\inetpub\wwwroot (IIS root)
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

## Copy files from bin/publish in our sdk container into c:\inetpub\wwwroot
COPY --from=build /Publish. ./
```

As you can see in the example image, the entries are added incorrectly (spaces and line breaks) and the first entry is missing the first number (1). How can i fix this? Thank you

[image]